# Feature elimination to screen for multiple models using tidymodels

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels, r-recipes, r-parsnip

I am currently performing regression modeling, with a dataset that has number of features (*p*) higher than observations (*n*).
Typically `p = 10000` and `n = 30`. Furthermore, I'd like to [test many models](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html) and find the best one.

What I'm doing now is first to eliminate those features. Reducing it from 10K to 20-30, using
[step_select_mrmr()](https://stevenpawley.github.io/recipeselectors/reference/step_select_mrmr.html) or [step_select_vip()](https://stevenpawley.github.io/recipeselectors/reference/step_select_vip.html).  I achieved that by placing it at the top of my pipeline.
Then I would proceed with testing many models.

Is this approach reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonable as long as you are using resampling or a validation set to make sure that there is no information leakage.

We hope to have more recipe functions for supervised filters later this year  but Steven's are great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a generic answer to your question of the appropriate way to reduce the number of dimensions in such an extreme scenario. The appropriate or reasonable solution depends entirely on the meaning of the data. There is no generic answer that works for all kinds of data.

Before going further, I must note that with only 30 rows or so, you cannot meaningfully do machine learning--you would massively overfit the data with just about any technique you try. With so few rows, you are pretty much stuck with linear or logistic regression. And even then, you would have to reduce the 10,000 columns to just 1 or a maximum of 2 columns (and that's a stretch) to avoid overfitting. My rule-of-thumb is linear or logistic regression below 50 rows; general additive models (GAM) for 50 to 2,000 rows; then almost any machine learning technique beyond that.

But let me answer as if you had sufficient rows and columns for valid analysis. To simplify things, we could consider two very different scenarios, both with 10,000 columns, as you indicated is typical for your data.

First, perhaps many of the columns are correlated with each other and so there is a lot of redundancy. I would think that with correlated columns, the appropriate solution for dimension reduction would be principal component analysis (PCA) or something like that. So, you could reduce the 10,000 columns to just a few columns that capture and summarize the essential information in the 10,000 columns without throwing away most of the information. I would say that this is generally the best approach.

Second, you might have a case where the vast majority of columns are completely irrelevant; only a few are relevant--your essential task is to hunt for those few relevant columns. In this case, I recommend against feature selection criteria like `step_select_mrmr` or `step_select_vip` that are based on feature important ranks. Rather, I recommend criteria that depend on absolute values of feature importance with the view that you could have 5 relevant features or you could have 100 and you would want to identify and retain them all.